# Android Studio: Where are Manifest Merger Logs?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio, and trying to import a fairly old project from Eclipse into Android Studio.  I am getting the dreaded error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I have tried a number of the highly rated solutions already with no luck.  But my actual question is: **Where are these damned log files?!**

I can't troubleshoot more deeply **or** ask a more detailed question until I find and inspect the log files, which Android Studio seems to have hidden completely out of view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should see files like

For `**debug**` look at `app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt`

For `**release**` look at `app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt`

Comment: @Novak: OK, perhaps that message is referring to something else. You may want to edit your question and provide the complete output of the Gradle Console after an attempted build.

Comment: ...I actually don't. I see that directory, but it is empty.  Bearing in mind this is a fresh (today) install of Android Studio, is it possible some setting needs to be enabled to generate that log?  (I am grasping at straws.)

Comment: @Novak: "is it possible some setting needs to be enabled to generate that log?" -- not as far as I know. But, as I commented above (replying to your now-deleted comment), perhaps the message is in reference to something else. Seeing the full Gradle output might help.

Comment: Your pointer to the full Gradle output was enough to point me to the conflicting lines of the manifest file, which allowed me to fix it myself.  Thank you!

Comment: I have the same error but the path specified is empty. In another project I had this error, the file did exist but contained no error information. Therefore, this answer doesn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: On `react-native` the app/build... folder is inside /android/

Comment: React-native go can run the app without fully building. Force a build using EAS to get the merger logs.

Answer (score 25):

While this is not quite the answer to your question: In Android Studio, load the app's AndroidManifest.xml file, then click on "Merged Manifest" at the bottom. Studio will show a split view, which on the right includes recommendations for how to fix the problems. The fixes are clickable (like so much in Android Studio... except the hard-to-find things). When I encountered this problem a few minutes ago, clicking on them automatically applied them, and all the problems magically went away.

See [this Android Developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) for this and more information.

Comment: This is actually a very good way to solve the specific problem posed.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the log on the right? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard To be honest, I don't think that's the log, so much as Android's analysis of the log. When I was having trouble with this, I found the file referenced by the accepted answer, but it was a long, incomprehensible mess of messages, not one of which was obviously an error (a search on the word "error" turned up nothing).

Comment: Yes, the log didn't have error messages for some reason. This tip helped greatly.